# Should I add two event listeners to one single event?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to two functions to one button. The first one will be added anyway while the second function depends on a true/false condition.

The following code works, but should I do something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a button.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", test);

function displayDate() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}

function test() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "test";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, for sure. But don't forget in a huge amount of listeners will be more memory used. Don't forget to clear event listeners when you don't need them.

Comment: Event listeners have an optional `once` parameter for self-cleanup: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `condition`

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
let isEvent = true;

// Add 'Event'
btn.addEventListener("click", displayDate);

// Add conditional 'Event'
if (isEvent) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", test);
}

// OR
btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (isEvent) {
        test(e);
    }
});
```

**Notice:** *Do not forget to remove event*

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem I would make 1 function with a function within that makes  the decision for your condition.